# Entity Framework Core 2.0 mapping int to SQL Server smallint throws exception on query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I mapped an `int` property to `smallint` in SQL Server. When I query the database, I get the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: An exception occurred while 
>   reading a database value for property 'Tag.Count'. The expected type
>   was 'System.Int32' but the actual value was of type 'System.Int16'

I want to do it this way because if I use a `short` on the Entity, I end up having to write extra code to cast `short` to `int`.

Snapshot of relevant code:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    //Other properties
}

//In DbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Tag>().Property(m => m.Count).HasColumnType("smallint");
}

//query
var tags = await context.Tags.ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Minimal, Complete and verifiable example is missing:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PhilNDeBlanc not sure what you mean there. But I'll take a stab at it

Comment: Instead of `int` you should use `short` as type for `Count` property.

Comment: You'll have to use `short` I think. If you don't want to do casts throughout your code you could add an unmapped `int` property that gets/sets your `Count` property and use that in your code instead.

Comment: @CodeNotFound @Valuator Sorry, the problem is with `enum`s. Posted new [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297148/entity-framework-core-2-0-mapping-enum-to-tinyint-in-sql-server-throws-exception)

Answer (score 2):

Change `int` to `int16` as `SMALLINT` is 16 bits and `int` is 32 bits. 
So 32 bits can't be converted to 16 bits. You can use `short` datatype also.

```
public class Tag
{
    public int16 Count { get; set; } 
    // or, 
   /* public short Count { get; set; } */

    //Other properties
}

//In DbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Tag>().Property(m => m.Count).HasColumnType("smallint");
}

//query
var tags = await context.Tags.ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Sorry, been a while since working with EF Core. The problem is with `enum`s. Posted new [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297148/entity-framework-core-2-0-mapping-enum-to-tinyint-in-sql-server-throws-exception)