# Entity Framework Core 2.0 mapping enum to tinyint in SQL Server throws exception on query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I get the following exception when I try to map an `enum` to `smallint` in `OnModelCreating`:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.Int32'.

I want to do this because in SQL Server an `int` is 4 bytes while a `tinyint` is 1 byte.

Relevant code:
Entity:

```
namespace SOMapping.Data
{
    public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public TagType TagType { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TagType
    {
        Foo,
        Bar
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SOMapping.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Tag>().Property(m => m.TagType).HasColumnType("smallint");

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

Query:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SOMapping.Data;

namespace SOMapping.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

        public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        {
            _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var tags = _applicationDbContext.Tags.ToArray();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can make this work so that I don't have to use 4 times as much space with all my `enum`s?

Answer (score 21):

Base type of enum and type of column must be same.
Start from changing base type for your enum:

```
public enum TagType: byte
```

And your need remove

```
... .HasColumnType("smallint");
```

then column would be automaticaly tinyint, or set it manualy:

```
.HasColumnType("tinyint");
```

Comment: You rock!! Thank you. The perils of working against `inMemoryDatabase`. Lotta refactoring to do